# What is extent size in volume groups?

Tags: disk-volume

What is extent size in volume groups? I have a very small volume, like 5mb, I need to set an appropriate extent size, but I do not know what it is.

Comment: What are you talking about? More details...

Comment: I mean the command "vgcreate --physicalextentsize"

Comment: So, I assume you are talking about Linux LVM. Why don't you tell this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The physical extent (PE) size is the basic unit out of which logical volumes are created. It defines the minimum size of a volume and the possible increments (having a 4MB PE size would mean the minimum volume size is 4MB and you can grow it in 4MB increments).

Making the PE too small wouldn't be recommended, as the maximum volume size is 65,536 PEs, so if you reduce this to 1MB, you end up with volumes not larger than 64GB.

Comment: Note that in lvm2 the restriction of 65K extents has been removed. https://linux.die.net/man/8/vgcreate - see `-s` switch.